# Parse arabic date in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

In an application that I'm writing I want to parse a specific date which is in the arabic language in c#. For example the date could look like this: ٣٠.١٢.١٩٨٩

But I want this output: 30.12.1989

My question is how to do that in c# to get a DateTime object out of this string.

Can anyone tell me how to to this?

Comment: I voted for repoen because I don't think this is _exact_ (close but not exact) duplicate because this question is all about how to parse Eastern Arabic numerals but duplicate question and two answer (which both are quite correct of course) is about RTL characters,  and other topics. If you _still_ think this is exact duplicate, please vote to close and/or ping me as well so I can close it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Eastern Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) does not supported by `DateTime` parsing methods, they only accepts [Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals).

On the other hand, [`char.GetNumericValue` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getnumericvalue) is quite good to get a floating-point representation of a numeric Unicode character as a `double` which perfectly successful for Eastern Arabic numerals as well.

If your string is always `dd.MM.yyyy` format based on those numerals, you can split your string with `.` and get their numeric values from those character, parse to integer those parts, use them in a [`DateTime(year, month, day)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor and get it's string representation with `dd.MM.yyyy` format with a culture that using Gregorian Calendar as a [`Calendar` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.calendar) like `InvariantCulture`.

```
var s = "٣٠.١٢.١٩٨٩";
var day =   Int32.Parse(string.Join("",
                        s.Split('.')[0].Select(c => char.GetNumericValue(c)))); // 30
var month = Int32.Parse(string.Join("",
                        s.Split('.')[1].Select(c => char.GetNumericValue(c)))); // 12
var year =  Int32.Parse(string.Join("",
                        s.Split('.')[2].Select(c => char.GetNumericValue(c)))); // 1989

var dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 30.12.1989
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nEVpXA)</kbd>.

As an alternative, you can create your own `Dictionary<char, char>` structure and you can replace Eastern Arabic characters mapped with Western Arabic characters.

```
var mapEasternToWestern = new Dictionary<char, char>
{ 
    {'٠', '0'}, 
    {'١', '1'}, 
    {'٢', '2'}, 
    {'٣', '3'}, 
    {'٤', '4'}, 
    {'٥', '5'}, 
    {'٦', '6'}, 
    {'٧', '7'}, 
    {'٨', '8'}, 
    {'٩', '9'}
};
```

Comment: thank you very much Soner, that was exactly what i needed :)

Comment: @AndreasFritz Glad to help. But be careful, there is no _perfect_ way to parse all arabic digits because of RTL or other issues as duplicated link mentioned.

Comment: beautiful~......